# Login in remotely PHP

Tags: php

I am having some problems with the code to access a remote website `server2` from another website `server1`. The code I use from inside the server2 to log in is the following code:

```
require_once("http://server2.com/access/models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}

//Prevent the user visiting the logged in page if he/she is already logged in
if(isUserLoggedIn()) { header("Location: http://server2.com/access/account.php"); die(); }
```

What I do know is that I can not use require/include code as those codes are used to call the php file from inside the server. Does anybody know how, where or what is the code to login from a remote server to another server?

Comment: @Fred The same person did that Question. Within 1 hours he did 2 same question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of safety issues you cannot view external php files directly.

If you want to access information from server2 I suggest you create a RESTful service or some other API on the remote server for communication between your servers.